# Hive update with subquery

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to update a Hive table from subquery and I know hive doesn't support such updates. Is there any work-around for this?

My update looks like this

```
UPDATE tmp_aka
    SET guid = (SELECT mguid FROM tmp_maxs
                                        WHERE tmp_maxs.guid = tmp_aka.guid);
```

Comment: UPDATE works if you are on >0.14 and on tables that support transactions.

Comment: yeah that I know. actually my question was how to update table using subqueries. I'm using hive 2.1.0 on EMR

Answer (score 2):

May be you can create a table for your select statement result and insert a new value with insert into table select values from newly created table

Answer (score 2):

You could perform a join in the sub-query to get the same values as in your query above. Try using the following query:

```
UPDATE tmp_aka
SET guid = (SELECT mguid FROM tmp_aka tmp JOIN tmp_maxs ON tmp_aka.guid = tmp_maxs.guid);
```

Answer (score 2):

If  `tmp_maxs` contains all the records of `tmp_aka`, you can do it this way:

```
INSERT overwrite TABLE tmp_aka
SELECT tmp_aka.col1, tmp_aka.col2, …, tmp_maxs.mguid
FROM tmp_aka LEFT JOIN tmp_maxs ON tmp_aka.guid = tmp_maxs.guid
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare values from two tables, u need to JOIN tables and then compare the value in subquery. Hope, this will help u.

```
UPDATE tmp_aka
    SET guid = (SELECT t1.mguid FROM tmp_maxs t1 LEFT JOIN tmp_aka t2 ON t1.guid = t2.guid);
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simpler solution to your update

```
UPDATE tmp_aka
SET guid = (SELECT mguid FROM tmp_maxs
                                    WHERE tmp_maxs.guid IN tmp_aka.guid);
```